# How to open a PopupMenuButton?

Tags: dart, flutter

How do I open a popup menu from a second widget?

```
final button = new PopupMenuButton(
    itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
          new PopupMenuItem<String>(
              child: const Text('Doge'), value: 'Doge'),
          new PopupMenuItem<String>(
              child: const Text('Lion'), value: 'Lion'),
        ],
    onSelected: _doSomething);

final tile = new ListTile(title: new Text('Doge or lion?'), trailing: button);
```

I want to open the `button`'s menu by tapping on `tile`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This works, but is inelegant (and has the same display problem as Rainer's solution above:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey _menuKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final button = PopupMenuButton(
        key: _menuKey,
        itemBuilder: (_) => const<PopupMenuItem<String>>[
              PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text('Doge'), value: 'Doge'),
              PopupMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text('Lion'), value: 'Lion'),
            ],
        onSelected: (_) {});

    final tile =
        ListTile(title: Text('Doge or lion?'), trailing: button, onTap: () {
          // This is a hack because _PopupMenuButtonState is private.
          dynamic state = _menuKey.currentState;
          state.showButtonMenu();
        });
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: tile,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I suspect what you're actually asking for is something like what is tracked by https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/254 or https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8277 -- the ability to associated a label with a control and have the label be clickable -- and is a missing feature from the Flutter framework.

Comment: Thank you Eric! Yeah, the widgets described in those github issues are something that I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks  I used this solution

Answer (score 57):

I think it would be better do it in this way, rather than showing a PopupMenuButton

```
void _showPopupMenu() async {
  await showMenu(
    context: context,
    position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(100, 100, 100, 100),
    items: [
      PopupMenuItem<String>(
          child: const Text('Doge'), value: 'Doge'),
      PopupMenuItem<String>(
          child: const Text('Lion'), value: 'Lion'),
    ],
    elevation: 8.0,
  );
}
```

---

There will be times when you would want to display **_showPopupMenu**     at the **location where you pressed on the button**
Use GestureDetector for that

```
final tile = new ListTile(
  title: new Text('Doge or lion?'),
  trailing: GestureDetector(
    onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
      _showPopupMenu(details.globalPosition);
    },
    child: Container(child: Text("Press Me")),
  ),
);
```

and then _showPopupMenu will be like

```
_showPopupMenu(Offset offset) async {
    double left = offset.dx;
    double top = offset.dy;
    await showMenu(
    context: context,
    position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(left, top, 0, 0),
    items: [
      ...,
    elevation: 8.0,
  );
}
```

Comment: How can I use the onSelected property from the PopUpMenuButton into your method? Lets say for example, if value Doge is selected, I want to navigate to Doge.dart page

Comment: Perfect answer, I just had to replace 0 by other values: `RelativeRect.fromLTRB(left, top, left+1, top+1),`

Comment: i think this menu is just to show  not to prforme  any action

Comment: @Texv There is a 'onTap' property for click callback in PopupMenuItem class. You can use this.

Comment: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(left, top, 0, 0), shows menu behind Keyboard. But i want to show on top of opened soft Keyboard. Any Idea?

Answer (score 10):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Full code:**

```dart
class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<PopupMenuButtonState<int>> _key = GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton<int>(
            key: _key,
            itemBuilder: (context) {
              return <PopupMenuEntry<int>>[
                PopupMenuItem(child: Text('0'), value: 0),
                PopupMenuItem(child: Text('1'), value: 1),
              ];
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () => _key.currentState.showButtonMenu(),
        child: Text('Open/Close menu'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution to your question. You can provide a child to PopupMenuButton which can be any Widget including a ListTile (see code below). Only problem is that the PopupMenu opens on the left side of the ListTile.

```
final popupMenu = new PopupMenuButton(
  child: new ListTile(
    title: new Text('Doge or lion?'),
    trailing: const Icon(Icons.more_vert),
  ),
  itemBuilder: (_) => <PopupMenuItem<String>>[
            new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                child: new Text('Doge'), value: 'Doge'),
            new PopupMenuItem<String>(
                child: new Text('Lion'), value: 'Lion'),
          ],
  onSelected: _doSomething,
)
```

Comment: use the offset property to position it differently

Comment: How to use multi-level PopupMenuItems?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to achieve this behaviour. Although you can attach an `onTap` attribute to the tile, you can't access the MenuButton from the 'outside'

An approach you could take is to use [ExpansionPanels](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ExpansionPanel-class.html) because they look like ListTiles and are intended to allow easy modification and editing.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Material `showMenu` but you menu doesn't work properly or **opens in wrong place** follow my answer.

this answer is based on answer of Vishal Singh.

in `GestureDetector`
use `onLongPressStart` or `onTapUp` for sending offset to function.

```
onLongPressStart: (detail){
   _showPopupMenu(detail.globalPosition);
},
```

> onLongPress is equivalent to (and is called immediately after) onLongPressStart.

> onTapUp, which is called at the same time (with onTap) but includes details regarding the pointer position.

and for menu position do some thing like below

```dart
    position: RelativeRect.fromDirectional(textDirection: Directionality.of(context), start: left, top: top, end: left+2, bottom: top+2)
```

full code

```dart
    _showPopupMenu(Offset offset) async {
      double left = offset.dx;
      double top = offset.dy;
      await showMenu(
        context: context,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                Radius.circular(AppConst.borderRadiusSmall))),
        position: RelativeRect.fromDirectional(textDirection: Directionality.of(context), start: left, top: top, end: left+2, bottom: top+2),
        items: _getMenuItems(menu),
        elevation: 8.0,
      ).then((value) {
        value?.onTap.call();
      });
    }
```