# Flutter how to get a popup menu on a ListTile?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to get a popupmenu under a `ListTile`. The `title` displays a description, the `subtitle` displays the selected value with some message and the `onTap` opens the popupmenu in which a user can select a value.

I tried putting a `DropdownButtonHideUnderline` in the `subtitle`, but this displays an arrow and does not respond to the `ListTile` `onTab` obviously.

How can I get a popupmenu on a `ListTile`?

Comment: Could you share a code snippet so that I could help in exactly where you are wrong?

Comment: It is not so much that I'm wrong, but I have no idea whether this is possible and if so, how to tackle it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349013/how-to-open-a-popupmenubutton Look at the accepted answer, at the end he told this is missing feature in the current flutter version.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Maybe you can try PopuMenuButton,

```
PopupMenuButton<String>(
    onSelected: (String value) {
    setState(() {
        _selection = value;
    });
  },
  child: ListTile(
    leading: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.add_alarm),
      onPressed: () {
        print('Hello world');
      },
    ),
    title: Text('Title'),
    subtitle: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Sub title'),
        Text(_selection == null ? 'Nothing selected yet' : _selection.toString()),
      ],
    ),
    trailing: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
  ),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) => <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
        const PopupMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Value1',
          child: Text('Choose value 1'),
        ),
        const PopupMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Value2',
          child: Text('Choose value 2'),
        ),
        const PopupMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'Value3',
          child: Text('Choose value 3'),
        ),
      ],
)
```

Take a look at [How to open a PopupMenuButton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349013/how-to-open-a-popupmenubutton)

Comment: This is just perfect.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know the child property entirely replace the button content!

Comment: Is there a way to do this on long press and not just tapping?

Comment: @DanielVilela, in case you didn't find a solution, it is in the link user1111 shared